# The first letter is being repeated of the first word

Tags: c, file, binary, file-handling

I am reading text from a file and outputting it as binary. I have modified the binary conversion as per follows:

1. Each capital letter shall start with 01 and will be followed by 5 bits.
2. The 5 bits shall hold the value of the letter.
3. The letters will have the value as A-2,B-3,C-4,D-5...

For example: HI-> (0101001)(0101010)

My code snippet is as follows:

```
void printinbits(int n)
{
    for (int c = 4; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        long int k = n >> c;

        if (k & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }        
}

int main()
{
    //first letter is being repeated
    char check[200];
    FILE*fin= fopen("/Users/priya/Desktop/test.txt.rtf","r");
    while((fscanf(fin,"%199s",check))==1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(check);++i)
        {
            if(check[i]>=65&&check[i]<=90)
            {
                printf("01");
                int n=check[i];
                n-=63;
                printinbits(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**My input->**

```
HELLO
```

**My output->**

```
(0101001)(0101001)(0100110)(0101101)(0101101)(0110000)
```

(As you can see, the first letter H is being repeated)(Various letters are separated by brackets)

Comment: Suggestion: add some sort of delimiter to your output, otherwise, it';s tough to read and understand...

Comment: @SouravGhosh done.

Comment: Is the logic just converting the letter to a number and appending it onto `01`? suppose the letter is `C` then the number is `3` (displacement from `A`) into binary?

Comment: When I read from `stdin`, I get the desired behaviour without repetitions. You seem to be reading a Rich Text Format file as raw data. Could you try reading a plain text file?

Comment: Print the value of `check` in the `while` loop before the `for` loop.  Are you sure you don't have `HHELLO` in the file?  This is the most basic technique of debugging: print what the computer got to make sure it is seeing what you think it should be seeing.

Comment: @MOehm you were right! .rtf means rich text document. I had saved my file as .txt.rtf. That is why it was repeating the first character. Its fine now! Thanks. However, can you tell me why a rich text document shows such behaviour? Is there some kind of extra text/character padding at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of (c**p) material at the start of a `.rtf` file, and more still at the start of a `.doc` file, etc.  Be careful to save plain text as plain text.

Comment: I ran ,your code. The output seems to be correct

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler Appreciate it.

Comment: The [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) contains extra information in addition to the text you see. It is a text file with control sequences, e.g. `{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard HELLO \par}`. Your code considers only upper-case letters, so in this case you get the `H` from `Helvetica` and all letters of `HELLO`.

Comment: @MOehm Okay, so the extra H was from Helvetica font. I did not know that! So if I was using Arial, I would get a capital A right? At the beginning?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're observing, one of your loops has a glaring problem:  `for(int i=0;i<strlen(check);++i)`  This is an O(n^2) loop for no useful reason.  All you need to do is calculate the length *once* to reduce it to O(n).  *Always* think about the work your code is actually doing, and whether it makes sense.  You would never do it this way by hand, and it makes no more sense to do it this way when it's automated.

Comment: That's just an example taken more or less verbatim from the Wikipedia page; I have of course no idea what your actual file looks like. You can look at the raw data by opening the file as pure text. You should probably get a proper programming text editor. Don't use the standard Windows editors for example, which may add extensions and formatting to your files "in order to serve you better".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hex dump of a file `hello.rtf` containing the word `HELLO` in upper case. It was generated by TextEdit on a Mac.

```
0x0000: 7B 5C 72 74 66 31 5C 61 6E 73 69 5C 61 6E 73 69   {\rtf1\ansi\ansi
0x0010: 63 70 67 31 32 35 32 5C 63 6F 63 6F 61 72 74 66   cpg1252\cocoartf
0x0020: 31 34 30 34 5C 63 6F 63 6F 61 73 75 62 72 74 66   1404\cocoasubrtf
0x0030: 34 36 30 0A 7B 5C 66 6F 6E 74 74 62 6C 5C 66 30   460.{\fonttbl\f0
0x0040: 5C 66 73 77 69 73 73 5C 66 63 68 61 72 73 65 74   \fswiss\fcharset
0x0050: 30 20 48 65 6C 76 65 74 69 63 61 3B 7D 0A 7B 5C   0 Helvetica;}.{\
0x0060: 63 6F 6C 6F 72 74 62 6C 3B 5C 72 65 64 32 35 35   colortbl;\red255
0x0070: 5C 67 72 65 65 6E 32 35 35 5C 62 6C 75 65 32 35   \green255\blue25
0x0080: 35 3B 7D 0A 5C 6D 61 72 67 6C 31 34 34 30 5C 6D   5;}.\margl1440\m
0x0090: 61 72 67 72 31 34 34 30 5C 76 69 65 77 77 31 30   argr1440\vieww10
0x00A0: 38 30 30 5C 76 69 65 77 68 38 34 30 30 5C 76 69   800\viewh8400\vi
0x00B0: 65 77 6B 69 6E 64 30 0A 5C 70 61 72 64 5C 74 78   ewkind0.\pard\tx
0x00C0: 37 32 30 5C 74 78 31 34 34 30 5C 74 78 32 31 36   720\tx1440\tx216
0x00D0: 30 5C 74 78 32 38 38 30 5C 74 78 33 36 30 30 5C   0\tx2880\tx3600\
0x00E0: 74 78 34 33 32 30 5C 74 78 35 30 34 30 5C 74 78   tx4320\tx5040\tx
0x00F0: 35 37 36 30 5C 74 78 36 34 38 30 5C 74 78 37 32   5760\tx6480\tx72
0x0100: 30 30 5C 74 78 37 39 32 30 5C 74 78 38 36 34 30   00\tx7920\tx8640
0x0110: 5C 70 61 72 64 69 72 6E 61 74 75 72 61 6C 5C 70   \pardirnatural\p
0x0120: 61 72 74 69 67 68 74 65 6E 66 61 63 74 6F 72 30   artightenfactor0
0x0130: 0A 0A 5C 66 30 5C 66 73 32 34 20 5C 63 66 30 20   ..\f0\fs24 \cf0 
0x0140: 48 45 4C 4C 4F 7D                                 HELLO}
0x0146:
```

You may or may not be able to see the `H` of 'Helvetica' as the only other capital letter in the file — that would account for producing the output for HHELLO.  It looks like you might be on a Mac too, so maybe you'd see the same result — or, at least, an equivalent one.  (I used a homebrew hex dump program; you'd probably use `xxd -g 1 test.txt.rtf`, which would produce the hex with lower-case letters, and wouldn't include the final byte count line.)

You could, and should, print the data that your program reads in the loop, at least while debugging it, so that you can see what the program is processing.  This is a very basic debugging technique.

In TextEdit, you can switch between rich text and plain text with the 'Make Plain Text' or 'Make Rich Text' option under the Format menu, or using ⇧⌘T (shift command T) to toggle between the two modes.  Note how the file name changes as you do that.

<sup>*Community Wiki since [M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639670/the-first-letter-is-being-repeated-of-the-first-word?noredirect=1#comment60873976_36639670) the likely problem.*</sup>